# Which layer of the MVC pattern loads/saves data from/to a database?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have been trying to figure out which layer between the Model and Controller loads data from a text file.

I want to write a load method which loads a person's information from text file **info.txt** which stores the person information

I have a **Person class ( model)** and **PersonController class (controller)**

My question is, using the MVC design, where should I write the **Load method**?

Thank You

Comment: Please write one common util class which does file reading and writing and from Person service class  call the util class for loading file contents

Comment: It's better to add your code whatever you tried so far. So that your code can be corrected or errors can be identified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC, the responsibility to load data is in ... nowhere really. The controller should call something else that does the persistence. In fact, in a well organised app, it should call something that ends up calling the class that loads/stores data.

From Wikipedia

> Model–view–controller is a software design pattern commonly used for developing **user interfaces** [...]

So MVC helps to deal with the user-interface, but the core of your application, has to be built using a different pattern. The one I've used in the last ~10 years, and which I think it's quite alright, is Ports-and-Adapters (also called Hexagonal Architecture).

Links (from Alistair Cockburn wiki)

- https://wiki.c2.com/?PortsAndAdaptersArchitecture
- https://wiki.c2.com/?HexagonalArchitecture

If you can, get a copy of "Growing Object-Oriented Software guided by tests". It's an amazing book and has a very clear explanation of these ideas.